# Does 60 fps make sense for YouTube?

Tags: video-recording, youtube, framerate, production, recording

YouTube says one should upload videos in the frame rate in which the video has been recorded. But if I have yet to record, what frame rate should I choose?

I noted that videos downloaded from YouTube have mostly 30 fps but some have 24 fps. I haven't seen any frame rather other than these 2 in videos downloaded from YouTube yet.

Will YouTube show 60 fps videos to the user with 60 fps (if it's possible)?

There of course are the downsides:

- Raw material is bigger.
- Rendering takes longer.
- Rendered file is bigger.
- Upload takes longer. (My internet connection is very slow.)

So I want to know whether it even changes something in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has supported 60fps video [since 2014](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2014/10/30/youtube-60fps-video-is-here-and-it-looks-incredible/#5eb03291525f).  YouTube has a page that talks about video formats, codecs, framerates, etc., [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en).  It is up to the Browser and YouTube to negotiate what format, frame rate, etc., should be served for optimal playback.

If you only care about YouTube as a video display platform, and not at all about any other platform, then you have the freedom to choose any of its preferred formats, depending on what sort of upload traffic you can afford.  If you want to be able to play something on your local computers, TV monitors, etc., then you should pick the format most preferred by your most-preferred platform, and let everything else try to adapt to that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want "live" look and less stutter, then use 60p. If you want film-like motion then use 30p. Use 24p if you want to filmout (no one this nowadays) or you want to make a DVD (DVD support for progressive content is best in 24p mode, and it kinda spotty for 30p). Blu-ray can be made 24p, 30p or 60p, so see the first two points.